# fopen on internal memory path returns EISDIR, but nothing exists

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to write a file using ndk to /data/data/com.package/files/.

I use "/proc/PID/cmdline" to get the correct path for the application. The path is correct.

In java I called getFilesDir so the files path is created.

```
Log.d("MAIN", "Files dir: "+getFilesDir().toString());
```

My device is rooted, I can snoop on the path:

```
# ls -la /data/data/com.package
drwxrwx--x app_149  app_149           2013-04-26 16:33 cache
drwxrwx--x app_149  app_149           2013-04-26 17:06 files
drwxr-xr-x system   system            2013-04-26 18:26 lib
```

The files directory is empty.
When I try to create a file inside the files directory using fopen, it fails with EISDIR:

```
FILE *fp= NULL;
fp= fopen("/data/data/com.package/files/test.txt","w"); // FAILS with errno 21 (EISDIR)
```

EISDIR is supposed to say the the pointed file is a directory, but there is NO file inside the directory!

```
# ls -la /data/data/com.package/files
#
```

What can this be?

Comment: root privilege doesn't apply to the Dalvik machine nor native threads started from the Dalvik machine. You probably have to create a native linux executable and "shell" out to it from your Android app.